# Is there a way to change Firefox's default textbox font?

Tags: firefox, fonts

Is there a way to change Firefox's default Textbox font? Because that option is not in `Options -> Content -> Advanced`. Like here: http://www.google.com.tw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible by editing the userChrome.css file.
Maybe [this is a good starting point](http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html) for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change your language, not your font.

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Content+panel?style_mode=inproduct#Languages